# how to detect automatically mobile number in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to detect mobile number from device in android programmatically but not able to get mobile number. I have Google so much but not get proper method or code, I have used this line of code for it but it is not giving proper output-

```
 TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                     mPhoneNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();
```

My question is:-

> 1. Is is possible to detect mobile number programmatically in Android ? if yes please provide some method.

Please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: it is only possible in some phone models it depends on the manufacturer. Samsung it is not possible

Comment: No.That is the only way to get..but it will not work in all devices.